# javascript change class on click, keep css animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So I'm in need of a bit of help. I have an issue that requires javascript/css combination.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FW43u/2/)

I have the menu setup. As you can see, the arrows animate on hover, which is not what I want in this case.

I want the arrows/css to animate on click. So I'm not sure on how to do this, if I should use .hasClass in js and switch it on click. Also, how would I be able to define which menu item is opened (defined by class, instead of defined in js).

After clicking, I want the arrow to remain how it should after animating (i.e. open menu has arrow up, closed menu has arrow down).

Would I have to change the js alot or would it just be minimal edits.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Collapse everything but the first menu:
    $("#VerColMenu > li > a").not(":first").find("+ ul").slideUp(1);
    // Expand or collapse:
    $("#VerColMenu > li > a").click(function() {
        $(this).find("+ ul").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please start using the "Tidy Up" button on jsfiddle. It makes your code beautiful.

Comment: Fixed, sorry. Will remember for future fiddles

Comment: That's alright. BTW, I have provided you the code to keep the arrow the way it should remain after animating. Do you also want to retain the current on-hover animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to the second part of your question: http://jsfiddle.net/R7f2K/3/

Your HTML has been updated to change:

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-down vnavright"></i>
```

to

```
<i class="vnavright fa fa-angle-down"></i>
```

I have added this line to your JS code:

```
$(this).find("[class^='vnavright']").toggleClass('fa-angle-down fa-angle-up');
```

The CSS rules have been modified to use `#VerColMenu li a [class^="vnavright"]`.

While things are working as you had desired, I find the animation to be confusing.

Comment: Thanks. Would it still be possible to include the css animation in that? Or would that be something more dificult to implement?

Comment: Totally possible. We just have to use a different selector.

Comment: So something like creating a seperate class for angle up and angle down both with the css animation

Comment: See the updated answer. You should accept this by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: I've accepted this, thanks for your help. It all seems how I'd like it to be aside from the animations. Is it possible to trigger the animation onClick (i.e. only when you click the menu item)?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do that. Have a look at jquery's [animate method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Have a look at [this codepen](http://codepen.io/srig99/pen/KeswC) which does something similar.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm probably going to just get rid of the animation, it's not an asbolute need, and it won't hurt the design. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In the original HTML, you'll also probably want to change that first arrow's class to fa-angle-up :

```
    <ul id="VerColMenu">
        <li><a class="top-vnav">General <i class="fa fa-angle-up vnavright"></i></a>
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much.